# Jquery scroll function not working on iphone device

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a scroll function which, when the user scrolls a div appears and when they scroll up it disappears. Problem is when I am testing on a device (iphone) this is for mobile only, the div appears at the top when i scroll all the way to the top, on the chrome simulator it's fine, but on iphone chrome and iphone safari it appears at the top? Any ideas?

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            $('.scroll-div').show();
        } else if (st == lastScrollTop) {
            //do nothing 
            //In IE this is an important condition because there seems to be some instances where the last scrollTop is equal to the new one
        } else {
            $(".scroll-div").hide();
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
});
```

Comment: check if you have  `overflow-x: hidden` or `overflow-y: hidden` then you will not get value in `$(this).scrollTop()`

Comment: I don't have that on any of the elements

Comment: it might be there for the body tag or the root most html tag

Answer (score 0):

You can get scrolltop value using this code

```
scrollTop = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop)
```

JQuery method `$(this).scrollTop()` might return zero in IOS

Comment: Are you saying, the Jquery method is not suitable?

Comment: you can identify overflow hidden if exists, you can remove it, yes jquery might provide always zero of scrolling is hidden it is a kind of known issue